# ¿Como puedo crear un evento relacionado a un elemento Entry en tkinter en pyhton?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ya se enlazar eventos a botones para cuando se haga clic en un botón ocurra algo. Ahora necesito que cuando se haga clic en un elemento Entry (Cuadro de texto), también me enlace con un evento. Por ejemplo tengo un campo fecha en el que por defecto escribo "dd/mm/yyyy" y quiero que cuando el usuario haga clic en ese campo ese texto se borre
Gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que usar el método [`bind`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html#bind) del widget de turno, en este caso un Entry. El evento que hace referencia al click izquierdo es `'<Button-1>'`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.text = tk.StringVar()
        self.text.set("Escribe algo aquí...")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(bg='orange', textvariable=self.text, relief=tk.SUNKEN, width=50)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry.bind("<Button-1>", self.clear_entry)

    def clear_entry(self, event):
        self.text.set("")


if __name__ == "__main__":
     root = tk.Tk()
     app = App(root)
     app.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta